# FragmentGridPagerAdapter together with support fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

I develop an Android app that has a mobile and a wearable part. I put some common things in a shared library, like a fragment that is used on the mobile device and also the wearable. Unfortunately the fragment is extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but `android.support.wearable.view.FragmentGridPagerAdapter` can't provide such support fragments via `getFragment` (only `android.app.Fragment` is supported).

Is there a `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` that supports `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: `can't provide such support fragments via getFragment` That's **obvious**. Use `getSupportFragment()`, instead.

Comment: Unfortunately `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` has no method `getSupportFragment`.

Comment: Did you add this import `android.support.wearable.view.GridPagerAdapter`?

Comment: No, `android.support.wearable.view.FragmentGridPagerAdapter`. `GridPagerAdapter` does only support `View`s (not `Fragment`s).

Comment: Ah, OK, then... no, probably I'm not much into it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use support fragments. Its a while since I came across this but I ended up just changing to using fragments. At least it's straight forward.

Comment: This whole support fragment stuff is quite cumbersome. At first Google recommends to use the support libraries and then they are creating incompatibilities like this one.